# Cards for Monster, Spell and Trap interfaces

Tags: java, game, playing-cards, javafx

So I wrote a card game in Java/JavaFX but I don't particularly like this solution and I was wondering if you guys have any better solutions:

```
public static CardNode get(Card card, double nodeWidth, double nodeHeight, double imageWidth, double imageHeight) {
    if (card.isMonster()) {
        MonsterCardNode cardNode = new MonsterCardNode(nodeWidth, nodeHeight, imageWidth, imageHeight);
        cardNode.setCard(card);
        return cardNode;
    } else if (card.isSpell()) {
        SpellCardNode cardNode = new SpellCardNode(nodeWidth, nodeHeight, imageWidth, imageHeight);
        cardNode.setCard(card);
        return cardNode;
    } else if (card.isTrap()) {
        TrapCardNode cardNode = new TrapCardNode(nodeWidth, nodeHeight, imageWidth, imageHeight);
        cardNode.setCard(card);
        return cardNode;
    }
    return null;
}
```

CardNode and Card are abstract classes. They both implement interfaces *Monster*, *Spell* and *Trap*. Methods `isMonster`, `isSpell`, `isTrap` return a boolean and are essentially `instanceof` and flag checks. I was wondering if there is any better way to handle this with polymorphism.

---

Here is the usage of that static method.

```
model.getPlayer().getHand().addListener((ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Card> change) -> {
    while (change.next()) {
        if (change.wasAdded()) {
            change.getAddedSubList().forEach((card) -> {
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    CardNode cardNode = CardNode.get(card, 105, 145, 96, 105);
                    view.getPlayerView().getHand().getChildren().add(cardNode);
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You should add your cards implementation

Answer (score 2):

As a general principle, instead of asking an object what its type is, tell it what you want to do, and let overridden methods handle the differences between types:

```
return card.getCardNode(nodeWidth, nodeHeight, imageWidth, imageHeight);
```

and add a getCardNode abstract method to Card, so that each Card subclass can implement its own piece of the `get` logic.

Comment: It also removes the need to track these instance checks everywhere, which would even result in blowing up the application if you forgot.